# deserialize json response to c#

Tags: c#, json, json-deserialization

I am not able to deserialize following response :
My JSON IS

```
json is
{
  "disclaimer": "Exchange rates/",
  "license": "Data sourced from various providers",
  "timestamp": 1435813262,
  "base": "USD",
  "rates": {
    "AED": 3.672973,
    "AFN": 60.150001,
    "ALL": 126.7792,
    "AMD": 472.46,
    "ANG": 1.78875,
    "AOA": 121.253666,
    "ARS": 9.095239,
    "AUD": 1.307011,
    "AWG": 1.793333,
    "AZN": 1.04955,
}
}
```

Controller is :

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Index(Test1 values)
{

    string appid = values.apikey;
    HttpWebRequest request = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create("https://openexchangerates.org//api/latest.json?app_id=5db2fa81c8174a839756eb4d5a4a5e05");

    request.Method = "POST";

    using (StreamWriter streamWriter = new StreamWriter(request.GetRequestStream(), ASCIIEncoding.ASCII))
    {
        streamWriter.Write(appid1);
        streamWriter.Close();
    }

    string responseText = String.Empty;

    if (request.Headers.Count > 0)
    {

        using (StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(request.GetResponse().GetResponseStream()))
        {
            responseText = sr.ReadToEnd();

        }
    }

    var myObject = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(responseText);
}
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [Deserialize JSON with C#](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7895105/deserialize-json-with-c-sharp)

Answer (score 5):

Follow here : http://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/DeserializeObject.htm

Do not forget to declare a class for your deserialized object. It should contains fields that json object already has or some of them.

I dont know if your code fully works except deserializing process but there is a code example below for you to make you understand what i meant:

```
class MyClass
{
    public string disclaimer { get; set; }
    public string license { get; set; }
    public string timestamp { get; set; }
    ...
}

[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Index(Test1 values)
{
    ...
    var myObject = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<MyClass>(responseText);
    ...
}
```